# dangerouslySetInnerHTML error when nesting HTML within React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using a library that provides a component called `InputPassword` which returns an `input` area.

I need to place a `<label>` block *right beneath* the `<input>` block for some animations to work. So far I've made it possible via the following:

```
<InputPassword className="input__field input__field--kohana password">
    <label className="input__label input__label--kohana">
        <i className={"fa fa-fw icon icon--kohana fa-lock" }></i>
        <span className="input__label-content input__label-content--kohana">Password</span>
    </label>
</InputPassword>
```

Works like a charm!

However, my console complains with the following message on every keypress:
`Warning: input is a void element tag and must not have 'children' or use 'props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML'. Check the render method of InputPassword.`

How can I avoid this error?

Simply rewriting in this way does not do the trick:

```
<InputPassword className="input__field input__field--kohana password" />
<label className="input__label input__label--kohana">
    <i className={"fa fa-fw icon icon--kohana fa-lock" }></i>
    <span className="input__label-content input__label-content--kohana">Password</span>
</label>
```

Comment: Did you try the latter snippet, but wrapped in a single container element, as you should generally only return one element.

Comment: show, please, render method of `InputPassword` component

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have much control over the `InputPassword` component as it is from [this library](https://github.com/seethroughtrees/react-ux-password-field). You can find its [render](https://github.com/seethroughtrees/react-ux-password-field/blob/master/lib/react-ux-password-field.js) method here.

Comment: @adeneo the latter snippet simply does not work for the animations, because the result renders as follows:
`
<div>
    <input>
</div>
<label></label>
`

This is inherently different from the first snippet, which renders like:
`
<div>
    <input>
    <label></label>
</div>
`

which is the necessary format for the animation to function. Sorry about the bad formatting.

Comment: Not sure if this is the right way, but something like this should at least work -> https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/34318/